# Not able to add Dynos on Heroku

Tags: heroku

Settings:

1. I have one running 1web dyno on heroku and it works great
2. I have another one that's "sleeping"
3. I created a new app but somehow the dynos are not showing up.
4. I have a credit card plugged into Heroku and I am willing to pay for additional usage

When I try git push on the new app I get a timeout:

```
dsa002574:node-canvas mike.borozdin$ git push heroku master
ssh: connect to host heroku.com port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

When I try heroku scale I get an error as well:

```
dsa002574:node-canvas mike.borozdin$ heroku ps:scale web=1
Scaling web dynos... failed
 !    App must be deployed before dynos can be scaled.
```

Scaling from Heroku admin doesn't seem to work.  Here is a screenshot:
[image]

Any guesses as to why heroku won't let me scale?

Comment: cant you scale from the heroku admin directly ? does it work?

Comment: @mpm - no dice.  I uploaded a screenshot to just make sure I am using the right page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, your `git push` failed ("operation timed out"), so you haven't actually deployed an app.  As a result, Heroku's having trouble scaling the non-existent app :-)

Answer (score 2):

Do you have a procfile?
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile

This will specify what app to run, and therefore what to assign dynos to it.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't get a timeout when pushing, but the site failed with "No web processes running" and when I tried to ps:scale I got "App must be deployed before dynos can be scaled."

Turns out it was because I had created a local `heroku` branch instead of `master`, and when I pushed, it said "Pushed to non-master branch, skipping build." which took me a while to notice. So it didn't even try to deploy the app. Fixed by pushing to `master`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I also accidentally created multiple branches which prevented the thing from running.